# lcov + gcov-9 performance regression because of json usage

Tags: gcc, gcov, lcov

I have updated my build environment compiler from `gcc 5.5.0` to `gcc 9.3.0` and noticed coverage calculation performance regression.

It became **10 times slower** (5 hours vs 48 hours for whole project).

My investigation shows that in gcov-9 they started to use `json` format instead of `intermediate text format`.
This slowed down intermediate gcov-files creation and parsing.

Minimal example below:

```
> time geninfo --gcov-tool gcov-5 test5/CPrimitiveLayerTest.cpp.gcno 
Found gcov version: 5.5.0
Using intermediate gcov format
Processing test5/CPrimitiveLayerTest.cpp.gcno
Finished .info-file creation

real    0m0.351s
user    0m0.298s
sys     0m0.047s

> time geninfo --gcov-tool gcov-9 test9/CPrimitiveLayerTest.cpp.gcno 
Found gcov version: 9.3.0
Using intermediate gcov format
Processing test9/CPrimitiveLayerTest.cpp.gcno
Finished .info-file creation

real    0m8.024s
user    0m7.929s
sys     0m0.084s
```

I didn't find the way to return to old format but maybe there are any workarounds or patches.

P.S. I know about gcov's argument `--json-format`, but lcov1.15 can process either `json` format or so-called `intermediate text format`. At the same time gcov9 can output either `json` format or so-called `logfile` format files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation shows that this is because of `lcov 1.15` uses `JSON:PP` module for json parsing.
Replacing of `JSON:PP` to `JSON:XS` (fast parser) gives required speedup.

So I use next commands to reach it:

```
# patch geninfo to use fast json parser
> sudo sed -i 's/use JSON::PP/use JSON::XS/g' /usr/local/bin/geninfo

# install perl module
> sudo cpan install JSON:XS
```